# objective c get mac address from wifi point on iOS device and no see zero in address

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i use function and see

> ```
> BSSID = "d4:ca:6d:d4:e:89";
> SSID = "ExtremeFitness_FreeInternet";
> SSIDDATA = <45787472 656d6546 69746e65 73735f46 72656549 6e746572 6e6574>;
> ```

but mac address from wifi pointer d4:ca:6d:d4:0e:89

after, i compare current wifi bssid with mac address from database, compare NSString

why i not see 0 in this code ?

```
+(NSString *) getMac{

CFArrayRef myArray = CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
CFDictionaryRef captiveNetWork = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(myArray, 0));
//NSLog(@"Connected at : %@", captiveNetWork);
NSDictionary *myDictionnary = (__bridge NSDictionary *)captiveNetWork;
NSString *bssid = [myDictionnary objectForKey:@"BSSID"];

if (bssid.length == 0) {

    return @"";
}

return bssid;
}

-(void)compareMacAddress{

for (int i = 0; i < _clubs.count; i ++) {


    NSString *macFromClub = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _clubs[i][@"mac"]] lowercaseString];

    NSLog(@"%@", _clubs[i]);

    EFMacAddressUtil *macUtil = [[EFMacAddressUtil alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"%@", [[macUtil getMac] lowercaseString]);

    NSRange range = [macFromClub rangeOfString:[[macUtil getMac] lowercaseString]];

    if (range.length > 0) {

        [_clubInfo setObject:_clubs[i][@"address"]  forKey:@"address"];
        [_clubInfo setObject:_clubs[i][@"id"]       forKey:@"id"];
        [_clubInfo setObject:_clubs[i][@"ip"]       forKey:@"ip"];
        [_clubInfo setObject:_clubs[i][@"mac"]      forKey:@"mac"];

        _inClub = true;

        [_mainOfficeTableView reloadData];
        break;

    }else{

        _inClub = false;

        [_mainOfficeTableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

}

Comment: im not sure why that is happening, but im guessing its just interpreting the values as plain old hex, and 0e is effectively the same as e, so you could just write a little function to insert 0 if there are digits missing. unless someone comes up with an actual answer

Comment: As @Fonix said, 0e and e are numerically equivalent.  It just seems that the code inside the Captive Network framework doesn't add the leading 0 when converting to a hex string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved 
if my app see in mac address xx:xx:xx:e:xx:xx i make string xx:xx:xx:0e:xx:xx